# MySQL DATE_ADD does not work

Tags: sql, mysql, datetime

I have two columns: beginTime and duration. I'm trying to calculate the endTime. The problem is that i get empty results back.

I have tried several things.

```
DATE_ADD(startTime, INTERVAL `duration` MINUTE) AS endTime

DATE_ADD(startTime, INTERVAL '10' MINUTE) AS endTime

DATE_ADD(startTime, INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) AS endTime
```

But everytime the result is empty. startTime is not empty. It is a time field in the format 09:00:00.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DATE_ADD` will return `NULL` if the time format is incorrect, along with a warning:

```
mysql> \W
Show warnings enabled.
mysql> SELECT DATE_ADD('25:00:00', INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) AS endTime
    -> ;
+---------+
| endTime |
+---------+
| NULL    |
+---------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Warning (Code 1292): Incorrect datetime value: '25:00:00'
```

Also note that `'hh:mm:ss'` is not a correct datetime format. You need to have year, month and day also.

Could you please enable warnings in `MySQL` and repeat the query with your data?

Comment: This is the message I get when I exequte my query: Warning (Code 1264): Out of range value for column 'startTime' at row 1. Probably because of the wrong type. How can i add minutes to a time field?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(`startTime`, INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) AS endTime FROM `users` WHERE 1
```

Comment: What is the field-type of `startTime`?

Answer (score 0):

In DATE_ADD first parameter supposed to be Date field not Time field. Can you try changing the start time to Date format ('0000-00-00 00:00:00') and try?