# Adding certain minutes to time in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime

This question is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421409/mysql-dateadd-does-not-work)

I have a field which is a time-field (it does not need to be a datetime field, cause the date part makes no sense here). The value i want to add is in another field, in minutes.

So basicly, I want to add minutes to a time value. I have tried the DATE_ADD function, but it expects the date to be a datetime, with the datepart set. I also tried the ADDTIME function, but the problem here is that the duration field is in whole minutes, and not in the format hh:mm:ss, so it just adds it as seconds.

Does anyone know a way to accomplish this?

[edit]

This is the current query:

```
SELECT ADDTIME(startTime, duration * 60), startTime, duration FROM tblAppointment
JOIN tblThreatment ON tblThreatment.threatmentid = tblAppointment.threatment_id;
```

and this is the result:

```
+-----------------------------------+-----------+----------+
| ADDTIME(startTime, duration * 60) | startTime | duration |
+-----------------------------------+-----------+----------+
| 09:18:00                          | 09:00:00  |       30 |
| 10:09:00                          | 10:00:00  |       15 |
| 09:09:00                          | 09:00:00  |       15 |
| 10:57:00                          | 10:30:00  |       45 |
+-----------------------------------+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: Added an addition in response to your comment.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Addtime is definitely the way to go... to just add a certain amount of minutes you could do something like:

```
 AddTime('00:00:00', '00:10:00')
```

This would add 10 minutes to the first value.

You can read more on dev.mysql.com here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime

**EDIT:**

In addition to your comment. If you get the value to add in the format of `mm` and nothing else, then you could parse a time value with the `SEC_TO_TIME()` function. Like this:

```
SELECT ADDTIME(startTime, SEC_TO_TIME(duration*60)), startTime, duration
FROM tblAppointment
JOIN tblThreatment ON tblThreatment.threatmentid = tblAppointment.threatment_id;
```

This would return a Time in the `hh:mm:ss` minute format.

Answer (score 11):

A simple way to add & subtract intervals from dates and times is just to use `+` or `-` and the word `INTERVAL`:

```
SELECT startTime + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
```

You can add & subtract seconds, minutes, days, weeks, months, etc.. The full list is here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

> Date arithmetic also can be performed using INTERVAL together with the
>   + or - operator:
>
> ```
> date + INTERVAL expr unit 
> date - INTERVAL expr unit
> ```
>
> INTERVAL expr unit
>   is permitted on either side of the + operator if the expression on the
>   other side is a date or datetime value. For the - operator, INTERVAL
>   expr unit is permitted only on the right side, because it makes no
>   sense to subtract a date or datetime value from an interval.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps concatenate ':00' onto the end of the value from the minutes field before passing to `TIMEADD`? Or alternatively, multiply the value by 60.

Comment: Both don't work. With the concat version, I get times like 39:00:00, 25:00:00.

Comment: How do you manage that, if the minutes coming in are 00-59? or do you have things like 39:00 in your minutes field?

Comment: I really don't know. This is just what i'm getting. But this method wouldn't be very flexible in case you have durations of longer then 59 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

**TL:DR**

> multiply minutes by 100, not 60

**EXPLANATION**

If you want to add minutes in `MM` format, like it is in your example, and avoid converting it to `HH:MM:SS` format, you should multiply minutes by 100, not 60:

```
SELECT ADDTIME(startTime, duration * 100), startTime, duration FROM tblAppointment
JOIN tblThreatment ON tblThreatment.threatmentid = tblAppointment.threatment_id;
```

It's because as MySQL documentation says:

> For example, you might think of '1112' and 1112 as meaning '11:12:00' (12 minutes after 11 o'clock), but MySQL interprets them as '00:11:12' (11 minutes, 12 seconds). Similarly, '12' and 12 are interpreted as '00:00:12'.

So you don't want to count how many seconds you have (ex: 600 = 6 minutes, not 10 minutes as you'd think)

If you want to add 15 or 30 minutes, you simply add 1500 or 3000, and that's it.